# Validation Rule not shown on Standard Page Layout when Update from APEX

Tags: apex, javascript, validation, page-layout, validation-rule

I am having issues showing a custom Validation Rule Exception on my Standard Case Page Layout.

The scenario is that I have a custom button on the layout which calls a Webservice method in a custom Apex class. Depending on some variables the method updates the case in different ways. I have a validation rule on Case to prevent a certain type of save of a Case. In my class I have the following code (simplified) (c is the Case):

```
Database.SaveResult SR = Database.update(c, false);

if(SR.isSuccess()) {
    return 'Success';
} else {
    //The Update did not go through, see if it is a Validation exception -> present to user.
    //Otherwise create a regular error message.
    for(Database.Error err : SR.getErrors()){
        if(err.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION){
            return err.getMessage();
        }else{
            return 'other error';
        }
    }
}
```

The last part about checking statusCode I added just to verify.
My custom button looks like this (Javascript):

```
var res = sforce.apex.execute("ExampleClass","ExampleMethod");
if(res == "Dispatched" || res == "Ready for dispatch"){
    location.reload();
}else if(res != "" || res != null){
    alert(res); 
}
```

The alert and the last part with the getStatusCode was added just to verify so that I can see the validation exception somewhere. But my issue is that it is not shown in its intended place, on the Case Object. If I try to save the case inline style to fire the validation rule everything works as inteded and the regular error message is shown.

Can someone explain how I can show the regular error message on Case from my apex Method, or at least explain why it is not shown when I return from the Apex method?

Ciao!

Comment: so the `alert(res);`never displays after calling the webservice from the custom Button? See also: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/throwing-errors-on-a-standard-page-layout-using-apex

Comment: No it shows up and works properly. My issue was that I am not able to show the validation rule exception on the Page Layout (as is the case when you manually Edit the Case), after some further investigation it appears that this is not possible however. So for now I will have to continue using my other intended temporary fix using a pop up dialog (the alert part).

Comment: you could probably inject it with jQuery DOM manipulation (use Firebug to see what SFDC does) - technique, is, of course, fragile