# Calling a class and its method on a custom button click on a standard page

Tags: email, controller, custom-button

I have class from which is used to send email. Currently i have a VF page and the class as controller. And a button on the standard layout of the custom object. When i click on the custom button send email it redirect me to VF page and from where i am sending email. But i want to send email by clicking on the send email button on the standard with out redirecting to the VF page. How can i achieve it. Please guide me if anybody have any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by below steps

step 1) Create a button on standard button and button Behavior should be Execute JavaScript.

```
  A) In this button you have to write javascript and remember include below files
    1) {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/16.0/connection.js")} 
    2) {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/16.0/apex.js")}
```

step 2) You have to write a globle class in which you have to define a webservice method.
        Call this webservice method from button.

Now you need info, how we can call a method from javascript, so below links help you
http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/10/calling-apex-method-from-custom-buttom.html
http://salesforcesource.blogspot.in/2009/06/triggering-apex-method-with-custom.html

one more link with similar question
[Best practice for calling Apex methods from custom button?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12864/best-practice-for-calling-apex-methods-from-custom-button)