# Custom Button with Scripting

Tags: custom-button

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js"> </script >
<script src="/soap/ajax/37.0/apex.js"> </script >
function success() {
var alertString="Success!"; 
alert(alertString); 
}

sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
sforce.apex.execute("ChangeLogTriggerHandler", "UpdateOfSameObject","UpdateOnAnotherObject", {recordId :{!Change_Log__c.Id} " }, { onSuccess: success, onFailure: error });
```

How to Call two methods of handler class in Custom button scripting

In the above i am Used Class name as ChangeLogTriggerHandler

method1 : **UpdateofsameObject**

method2 : **UpdateofAnotherObject**

but its not workinng

Comment: srihari.. If you have 2 method you need to call 2 times..

Comment: metho params means..i have two params in one method:{MethodParam:'List<Change_Log__c> newlist '} is this correct

Comment: yes for example if you method accept two parameters. then call like `sforce.apex.execute("myClass","makeContact",
                             {firstParam:"firstParamValue", SecondParam:"SecondaParamValue"});` this way you can pass multiple parameters

Comment: {!requireScript("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")} 

var retStr; 
retStr = sforce.apex.execute("ChangeLogTriggerHandler", "UpdateOfSameObject",{List<Change_Log__c> newlist :"Trigger.New"} {Record ID:'{! Change_Log__c.Id }'}); 
retStr = sforce.apex.execute("ChangeLogTriggerHandler", "UpdateOnAnotherObject", {List<Change_Log__c> newlist :"Trigger.New"}{Record ID:'{! Change_Log__c.Id }'}); 


alert('The method returned: ' + retStr); 

document.location = '/{!Change_Log__c.Id}';  its giving unexpected token error

Answer (score 1):

The syntex to call is:

```
// call apex webservice method
        sforce.apex.execute("ClassName", "MethodName", {MethodParam:'value'});
```

For more information see this thread [how to call remote action in javascript button without using vf page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122259/how-to-call-remote-action-in-javascript-button-without-using-vf-page/122263#122263)

Comment: Thank u Frodo...but i hav two methods

Comment: call it second time :)

Answer (score 1):

call one method after another.

```
sforce.apex.execute("ChangeLogTriggerHandler", "UpdateOfSameObject", {MethodParam:'value'}); 
sforce.apex.execute("ChangeLogTriggerHandler", "UpdateofAnotherObject", {MethodParam:'value'});
```

or

create a single method in your class ChangeLogTriggerHandler which calls both method internally and call that method from your script.

Comment: how to create a single method can u tell me the synatx plz

Comment: @srihari copy the same style as UpdateOfSameObject() or UpdateofAnotherObject().